# add pair (i,0) to a list with a broken ascending order

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, addition

i want to make a simple loop where i fill a list with broken ascending order with (i,0)

```
 [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)] ==> [(0,0),(1,5),(2,0),(3,2),(4,3),(5,0),(6,0),(7,1)]
```

Heres my approach

```
    l = []
    i = 0
    for (a,b) in [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)]:
        if a != i:
            l.append((i,0))
        l.append((a,b))
        i = i + 1
    return l
```

I know what the problem is but i cant find any clever solution to my problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Having a little fun with dicts...

```
>>> a = [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)]
>>> [*(dict.fromkeys(range(a[-1][0]), 0) | dict(a)).items()]
[(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1)]
```

Comment: Clever but could do with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple variation on your original code is to insert the intermediate tuples in a while loop:

```
l = []
i = 0
for (a,b) in [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)]:
    while i < a:
        l.append((i,0))
        i += 1
    l.append((a,b))
    i += 1

print(l)
```

Output

```
[(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1)]
```

And here is yet another way to do it in a different manner:

```
d = dict([(1,5), (3,2), (4,3), (7,1)])
l = [(i, 0) if i not in d else (i, d[i]) for i in range(max(d)+1)]
print(l)

# [(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1)]
```

This converts the initial list of tuples into a dictionary, iterates over the possible indices (first element of each tuple) and selectively inserts missing tuples or existing tuples as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension with your list temporarily converted to a dictionary:

```
L = [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)] 

[(i,d.get(i,0)) for d in [dict(L)] for i in range(max(L)[0]+1)]

[(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

create another list with all the first values of `lst` the use this list to check whether
the element exists in the first list. if it doesn't exist append `(i, 0)` else append the element from list 1 using `lst[lst2.index(x)]`

here is an example

```
lst =  [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(9,1)] 

lst2 = [x[0] for x in lst]

lst3 = []
for x in range(lst2[-1]+1):
    if x not in lst2:
        lst3.append((x, 0))
    
    else:
        lst3.append(lst[lst2.index(x)])
    
print(lst3)
```

same thing using list comprehension

```
lst3 = [(x, 0) if x not in lst2 else lst[lst2.index(x)] for x in range(lst2[-1]+1)]
```

your solution doesn't work because your `i` goes only till 3 whereas it should go till 7

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
i = 0
data = [(1,5),(3,2),(4,3),(7,1)]
num = (max(data))[0]

#creating List in asceding order since we cannot update tuple.
for i in range(0,num+1):
    lst = list((i,0))
    l.append(lst)
# Updating new list with tuple value.
for a, b in data:
    for ele in l :
        if a == ele[0]:
            ele.insert(1,b)
            ele.pop()


print(l)
```

output

```
[[0, 0], [1, 5], [2, 0], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 1]]
```